# Command prompt not opening in windows 10

Tags: cmd

I am trying to open the command prompt but if I open it just opens for a second then gets closed. I also use the command prompt for vscode and I am not able to open the terminal in vscode as well. I tried restarting my computer several times but still, the command prompt doesn't open.

Please suggest a solution from which I can open my command prompt

Comment: @KJ I'm not  able to open that file as well

Comment: I did  that it is not opening in notepad but do you know how can I fix if my %comspec%`is corrupted

Comment: I have tried cmder but i was using that from a long time now and antivirus did not report anything I have just installed anaconda this morning and from that time I am having this problem

Comment: the value is of the comspec is pointing to my cmd.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235189/discussion-between-zain-and-k-j).

Answer (score 11):

I did have the same problem.
The following method worked for me.

Open Powershell (Admin) and enter:

```
echo off
reg delete "HKCU\Console" /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v "AutoRun" /f
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v "AutoRun" /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File 
Execution Options\cmd.exe" /f
echo done
```

Found this on a comment from Mr. Holman Calda in this video [How to Fix Command Prompt(CMD) Not Working/Opening in Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-e5owEbGSc&ab_channel=Tricknology).

Comment: Worked! In my case only the first two deletes had effect.